# The view lessons.views.login didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-views

i started to learn django,
im getting The view lessons.views.login didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
i dont know where i'm making mistake.

my HTML codes

```
           <div class="formBx">
               <form method="POST">
               {% csrf_token %}
               <h2>Sign In</h2>
               <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
               <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
               <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
               <p class="signup">Don't have an Account?<a href="#" onclick="toggleForm();">Sign Up.</a></p>
               </form>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="user signUpBx">
           <div class="formBx">
               <form method="POST">
               {% csrf_token %}
               <h2>Create an account</h2>
               <input type="text" name="username1" placeholder="Username">
               <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
               <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Create Password">
               <input type="password" name="confirm" placeholder="Confirm Password">
               <input type="submit" name="" value="Register">
               <p class="signup">Already Have an Account?<a href="#" onclick="toggleForm();">Sign In.</a></p>
               </form>
           </div>
           <div class="imgBx"><img src="{% static 'img/logbg2.jpg' %}"></div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

My views.py codes

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render( request,"login.html")
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get("submit") == "Login":
            if request.method == "POST":
                username = request.POST["username"]
                password = request.POST["password"]

                user = authenticate(username = username,password=password)
                if user is None:
                     messages.info(request,"Username or password is incorrect")
                     return render(request,"login.html")
                messages.success("Logged In")
                login(request,user)
                return render(request,"index.html")
        elif request.POST.get("submit") == "Register":
            if request.method == "POST":
                username = request.POST["username1"]
                email = request.POST["email"]
                password = request.POST["password1"]
                confirm = request.POST["confirm"]

                if password and confirm and password != confirm:
                    newUser = (User.objects.create_user(username,email,password))
                    newUser.save()
                    login(request,newUser)
                    return render(request,"login.html")
                return render(request,"login.html")
```

so how can i solve this problem?

Comment: What if it a POST method, but `if request.POST.get("submit")` is not `"Login"` nor `"Register"`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so you were right, but why login or register is not working?

Comment: As stated by WillemVanOnsem , you should put a final else statement to be sure it would return a HttpResponse in both cases